# HttpPlatformHandler is deprecated by ASP.NET Core for IIS 10, what is the equivalent configuration?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-10, reverse-proxy, iis-10, httpplatformhandler

I was trying to download `httpPlatformHandler` and I [discovered](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/105) that it has been deprecated by ASP.NET Core.

Now if you want a web app to sit behind IIS, you have to use ASP.NET Core instead.

How does this change the configuration?

Before what I had was something like the following:\

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
           <add
               name="httpplatformhandler_rootWiki"
               path="*"
               verb="*"
               modules="httpPlatformHandler"
               resourceType="Unspecified"
               requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform
           stdoutLogEnabled="true"
           stdoutLogFile=".\node.log"
           startupTimeLimit="20"
           processPath="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
           arguments=".\node_modules\tiddlywiki\tiddlywiki.js ./wiki --listen port=PORT"
        >
           <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="Production" />
           </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I suggest you  open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited the tag to point out that you were misled by an irrelevant article (only ASP.NET Core applications should switch to ASP.NET Core module),

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpplatformhandler/info

Comment: I see they (or you) also closed the ticket.

So, is only deprecated for ASP.NET Core applications?  So they're keeping it around?